# Linux reads ahead when concurrent reads done on same file

Tags: linux, performance, io

Linux performs readaheads (specified in /sys/block//queue/read_ahead_kb) when a file is read sequentially.

**Interested OS** : Red Hat Linux
**Interested File System** : xfs, ext4

**What is the criteria for deciding a sequential read is done ?** Consider multiple concurrent reads done on same file using pread (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html) with same or different FDs.

e.g.

Same FD. reads at positions 10-20-30-78-89(out of seq reads) -40-50-60-70 - 23-34 (out of seq reads)- 80-90-100...

Could above subtle out-of-sequence reads avoid readaheads in this case ?

If so, would using two different FDs solve this issue (i.e. a separate FD used for reads at 78-89-23-34) ? (i.e. readaheads will happen as usual for 10-20-30-40-50 read)

Answer (score 4):

> Can above subtle out of sequence reads could avoid readaheads in this case?

Yes, out-of-sequence reads from the same file descriptor can affect readaheads, but the kernel tries to take this into account — at least for small “random” reads in parallel with sequential reads. See [the description of the on-demand readahead design](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.8/source/mm/readahead.c#L342), in particular:

> In interleaved sequential reads, concurrent streams on the same fd can
> be invalidating each other's readahead state. So we flag the new readahead
> page at (start+size-async_size) with PG_readahead, and use it as readahead
> indicator. The flag won't be set on already cached pages, to avoid the
> readahead-for-nothing fuss, saving pointless page cache lookups.

You can see where this fits in by looking at [`ondemand_readahead`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.8/source/mm/readahead.c#L435), in particular [its call to `try_context_readahead`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.8/source/mm/readahead.c#L511) and the surrounding comments.

As always when trying to remove performance bottlenecks, you shouldn’t take potential bottlenecks into account except as hints: you should devise your own benchmarks and analyse the performance characteristics of your specific scenarios. It could be the case, for example, that your out-of-sequence reads only hit pages which are already in the page cache as a result of readahead on your sequential reads.

Comment: thx for the information, will using a different FD solve this issue ?

Comment: First you need to determine whether you actually have an issue; have you done so already?

Comment: kindly pls note that this question was asked during design stage. With a theoretical background (+ any experience shared by other devs who dealt with similar cases) I can design my software to work optimally (i.e. in this case best read rate).